# Images on top of each other while centered vert. and hor

Tags: css, alignment, center, fadein, fadeout

I have looked up some tips about how to center a div in the middle of the page. I used this method:

```
width: 750px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -200px;
margin-left: -375px;
```

So, now that the div is in the middle of the page, I need some images inside of it to line up directly on top of one another. If I do this, I can fade them out using jQuery, revealing the new image.

Now, I tried many different techniques to line them up, but none work when they are centered like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="choose" align="center">
    <h2 id="question">Rock, paper, or scissors?</h2>

    <img src="Images/Rock.png" id="rock">
    <img src="Images/Result/Red Rock.png" id="Selected" style="opacity:1">
    <img src="Images/Paper.png" id="paper">
    <img src="Images/Result/Red Paper.png" id="Selected" style="opacity:1">
    <img src="Images/Scissors.png" id="scissors">
    <img src="Images/Result/Red Scissors.png" id="Selected" style="opacity:1">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.choose {
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -375px;
}

.choose img {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

How do I do it?

This is a rock paper scissors game if you hadn't noticed. [Here's what I've made so far.](https://747d6108ac1130fc3601936220515b351efca1a4.googledrive.com/host/0B4rWYiw5-JZtfjJpT2M0WUNRRGtWQ250RElDc2QxRUc2aEdzajFERWkzVUVTd0pkNlY3LXc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the images with `absolute` in the same coordinates so they stack on top of each other.

When your element has a specific width, `left:0; right:0; margin:auto;` is a cool way to horizontally center it in its `relative` parent. Same method works for vertical centering.

```
.choose img {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

You can also use this method to offset elements from the center.

```
.choose img.rock {
    left:-300px;
}

.choose img.sci {
    left:300px;
}
```

Rock will be 300 to the left and scissors 300 to the right.

Comment: This works partially, but now all the images are in the same spot. I need three groups of two images.

Comment: That's not apparent in your original question. Anyways I added a little extra to my answer.

Comment: So I switched the position of the regular and selected elements, and simply added a absolute position attribute to each. Boom.